# Making node.js use bash PATH

Tags: bash, node.js, imagemagick, osx-lion, node-imagemagick

I'm trying to use imagemagick's "identify" from node.js, but it's not working. I have installed imagemagick using

```
brew install imagemagick
```

and it's in /usr/local/bin/identify etc.

I have created a script to start my server like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "imagemagick: `which identify`"
/Users/myname/.nvm/v0.6.10/bin/node /path/to/server.js -g /some/directory/argument -port 8475
```

When I run the script from Terminal (Mac OS X 10.7), the output is as follows:

```
imagemagick: /usr/local/bin/identify
[... output from node.js comes here ...]
```

However, later on the script complains that `identify` could not be found. Make sure you have it installed and in your path etc.

The node.js imagemagick module calls `childproc.spawn('identify', args);`.

How can I make node.js use the same PATH as the bash script?

Comment: `spawn()` can find all executables in my $PATH just fine, but I notice you're using an old Node (0.6) and I only tested with 0.8 and 0.10. You could set the path explicitely, see [this part of node-imagemagic](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick/blob/master/imagemagick.js#L178). Also, [spawn supports passing environment variables](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), but I don't know if Node 0.6 supported that.

Comment: I changed the line in node-imagemagick to `exports.identify.path = '/usr/local/bin/identify';` but it still can't find it...I think the error has to be somewhere else. I'll have a look around.

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to change the node-imagemagick code, `var im = require('imagemagick'); im.identify.path = '...'` would have sufficed (because it's exported) :)